# I need an experienced perspective about Helper class

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I started learning javascript and nodejs. I use express for HTTP handling and I coded a class for checking missing parts and I am wondering, is it the correct way.

What the **checkEmpty** method doing is checking missing parts and returns an array that missing parts. Here is my helper class;

```
class Helper{
  /**
   * @param {String Array} areas 
   * @param {Object} data 
   * @returns {Array}
   */
  checkEmpty(areas, data){
    let result = [];
    areas.forEach(area => {
      if (!data[area]) {
        result.push(area);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
}

module.exports = Helper;
```

I create middleware for register request and I want to check is required areas empty or not. I send **what has to check** and **my request body** as **parameters**.

```
const Helper = require('../helper/Helper');

module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    let result = new Helper().checkEmpty(['name', 'email', 'password'], req.body);
    if(result.length > 0){
        res.json({
            error: true,
            message: 'Missing part(s)',
            empty: result
        });
    }else{
        next();
    }
};
```

Output looks like;

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Missing part(s)",
    "empty": [
        "name",
        "password"
    ]
}
```

So as I said, I am wondering, is it the correct way to do that, and if it is correct then how file structure has to be, or is there a tool already in **express** or **nodejs**?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: You could use the express validator library to validate the request body if that meets your requirements.

Comment: @omeanwell Yes i did not find anything about body-parser's validate but i found express validator too. Thank you for your comments and I want to ask one more thing. Lets imagine there is no tool for that, does my solution good or bad ? I mean what makes my solution better ? Do you have any feedback about that ?

Comment: Your solution looks like a good. The things express validator does is to basically check the type of the variables passed. E.g. is it a string, number, object. Is it what you expect it to be. So to improve your solution you could add things like checkEmail() etc.

Comment: @omeanwell Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries at all!